# Unix extract lines in between 2 lines and store them in respective files

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file like below in file allreport.txt:

```
11:22:33:456        Script started                  Running: first_script
11:22:34:456        GetData - Read                  Read 12 Bytes
11:22:34:456        SetData - Write                 Write 12 Bytes
11:32:33:456        Script started                  Running: second_script
11:32:34:456        GetData - Read                  Read 12 Bytes
11:32:34:456        SetData - Write                 Write 12 Bytes
11:42:33:456        Script started                  Running: third_script
11:42:34:456        GetData - Read                  Read 12 Bytes
11:42:34:456        SetData - Write                 Write 12 Bytes
11:52:33:456        Script started                  Running: fourth_script
```

My requirement is that I need to extract the '....' lines which are in between '*scripts'. I tried something like below:

```
grep 'Running:' allreport.txt | sed 's/[^ ]* //' | cut -d":" -f2 | tr '\n' ' ' | awk -v col=1 '/$col/,/$($col+1)/ allreport.txt  > $col'
```

But after execution of the command I see no output and no result files also created?

How can I achieve the same - the expected output is to have files like first_script, second_script and so on and each of the files contains logs of its run - example first_script should have below lines only:

```
11:22:34:456        GetData - Read                  Read 12 Bytes
11:22:34:456        SetData - Write                 Write 12 Bytes
```

Similarly second_script should have below lines and so on:

```
11:32:34:456        GetData - Read                  Read 12 Bytes
11:32:34:456        SetData - Write                 Write 12 Bytes
```

Comment: Don't provide links or images, simply create and post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that adequately represents your real data in your question. If it's too big for you to post and/or provide the expected output for then it's certainly far too big to expect us to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [csplit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html) utility to split a file based on content:

```
csplit allrep.txt /[[:space:]]Running:[[:space:]]/ '{*}'
# produces xx00 - xxNN files based on that match
```

Some versions do not support `'{*}'`. If that is the case, you need to supply the number of splits in the `{}`. You could do:

```
csplit allrep.txt /[[:space:]]Running:[[:space:]]/ "{$(awk '/\sRunning:\s/{cnt++} END{print cnt-1}' allrep.txt)}"
```

If you want the file names, I would do something like this in `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{fn="0000 - Header"}
{sub(/\r$/,"")}   # the file you uploaded has \r\n endings
$(NF-1)=="Running:" {close(fn); fn=sprintf("%04d - %s.txt", ++fc, $NF)}
{print >fn}
' allrep.txt
```

By adding a numeral in front, 1) that takes care of any dups and 2) allows you to see the order.

Comment: Thanks the above mentioned csplit command helped me out - thanks a lot - but is it possible that the outfile name which is format xxNN where NN are numeric digit be named as script name like - first_script etc?

Comment: No, there isn't an easy way to get arbitrary file names out of `csplit` directly.

Comment: You can then have a Bash script that reads the first line to get the file name. You then need to deal with the same issue as the `awk` solution here: What about dups?

Comment: Thanks a lot - it solved my issue and thanks a ton

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples only, please try following. As an output it will create 3 files named `first_script`, `second_script` and `third_script` with shown samples.

```
awk -F': ' '/Running/{close(outFile);outFile=$2;next} {print > (outFile)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, making field separator as `:` then checking if line has `Running` in it then set output file name as 2nd field. If line is NOT having `Running` then print that line into output file. Also making sure to close the output file in backend to avoid "too many opened files error" here.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this awk also:

```sh
awk '$(NF-1) == "Running:" {close(fn); fn = $NF; next} {print > fn}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem seems to be that you have some shell script code inside the quotes of your Awk script ... but also more fundamentally, your script is much too complex and weird.

```sh
awk '/Running:/ { close(c); c++; next }
    { print >c }' allreport.txt
```

Comment: I get below error "awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=allreport.txt FNR=1) fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value

Comment: Well we can have a constant file name for output then like script1.log, script2.log and so on later I can rename them

Comment: Oh my bad, it looked like two separate lines on mobile. Updated now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'sub(/.*Running: /,""){ close(out); out=$0; next } { print > out }' allreport.txt

$ head *script
==> first_script <==
11:22:34:456        GetData - Read                  Read 12 Bytes
11:22:34:456        SetData - Write                 Write 12 Bytes

==> second_script <==
11:32:34:456        GetData - Read                  Read 12 Bytes
11:32:34:456        SetData - Write                 Write 12 Bytes

==> third_script <==
11:42:34:456        GetData - Read                  Read 12 Bytes
11:42:34:456        SetData - Write                 Write 12 Bytes
```

Comment: Thanks but I getting an error "awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=allreport.txt FNR=1) fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value

Comment: Then the input you're running it against doesn't look like the sample input you provided or you did something wrong when copy/pasting the script I provided. Given the input you told us you have the script in my answer **will** produce the output you asked for as shown in my answer.

Comment: There is a header portion to the actual file that causes the first few lines to be written to a null file name. You need a default value for `out`

Comment: @dawg Ah, I see, too bad the OP didn't include that in the sample input/output in their question. I wonder if they wanted the header to appear in every output file or be discarded or get it's own file or something else. Oh well....